# How to parse with one regular expression this string in Python

Tags: python, regex

I need to parse this string, with only one regular expression in Python. For every group I need to save the value in a specific field. **The problem is that one or more of the parameters may be missing or be in a different order.** (i.e. `domain 66666 ip nonce`, with the middle part missing)

`3249dsf 2013-02-10T06:44:30.666821+00:00 domain constant 66666 sync:[127.0.0.1] Request: pubvalue=kjiduensofksidoposiw&change=09872534&value2=jdmcnhj&counter=232&value3=2&nonce=7896089hujoiuhiuh098h`

I need to assign:

- `time=2013-02-10T06:45:30.666821+00:00` (constant format)
- `domain=domain` (string)
- `code=66666` (integer)
- `ip=127.0.0.1` (string)
- `pubvalue=kjiduensofksidoposiw` (string of fixed length)
- `nonce=7896089hujoiuhiuh098h` (string)

**EDIT**

This is an example on how the string can vary:
*123dsf 2014-01-11T06:49:30.666821+00:00 google constant 12356 sync:[192.168.0.1] Request: pubvalue=fggggggeesidoposiw&nonce=7896089hujoiuhiuh098h*

Thank you in advance for showing me the way.

Comment: When you need to grab values out of a string with a variable number of different items in a variable order, it is not a job for one regex.  Why do you have this requirement for a single regex?

Comment: if the string isn't regular, then you're asking for hassle by trying to apply one regular expression to it

Comment: More detail is required on how the string to be parsed may vary. Please also provide code to adapt.

Comment: Hello, the problem is that i need to parse 1-3 Gigabytes of text file and i think that by calling re.match() multiple times it will be much much slower then parsing everything at once. There are millions of lines

Comment: @NoobTom: I would say this is wrong! Because grouping and backreferencing and look aheads, -behinds and all this stuff, will be very slow, because your whole file will be interpreted in one step. I think there will be a lot of backtracking, which makes it slow.

Comment: Ok, thank you. So you suggest to re.match() every single pattern i need i.e. i call one re.match(ip_pattern) one re.match(time_pattern) on the same line of the file?

Comment: @NoobTom, I don't think you should call `re.match` on the entire pattern for each term.  Probably it would be better have intermediate steps, like: split the string on whitespace, split the request on `&`, then check the terms for the things you want.  If you can define exactly what will change and what won't, that will help you make the most efficient algorithm.  For example, if the time is always the second term, you can just take this instead of testing it.

Comment: @dan1111 's idea is a good way to do this! and yes, I ment to call re.match for each pattern, but before you should definitly split the file content up, to have shorter substrings of the file's content.

Comment: Yes, i process the file line by line. Thank you for sharing your knowledge guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably not a good idea to use one regex to parse the whole string.
but I think the solution is to use `named groups` (see: [Named groups on Regex Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html).
`Named groups` can be captured by `(?P<nameofgroup>bla)`

So you can match for example the ip with:

```
import re
str = "3249dsf 2013-02-10T06:44:30.666821+00:00 domain constant 66666 sync:[127.0.0.1] Request: pubvalue=kjiduensofksidoposiw&change=09872534&value2=jdmcnhj&counter=232&value3=2&nonce=7896089hujoiuhiuh098h"
print re.search("\[(?P<ip>\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})\]", str).groupdict()
```

Just extend this Regular expression with the patterns you need to match the other stuff.

and you can make the groups optional with placing a `?` after the group's parantheses, like: `(?P<ip>pattern)?`. If a pattern could not be matched the element in the dict will be `None`.

**But notice:** It is **not** a good idea to do this in only **one** Regex. It will be slow (because of backtracking and stuff) and the Regex will be long and complicated to maintain!

Comment: Thank you i did not know about named groups! this is for use great help for assigning the match to a variable!

Comment: So, have a look at the like to my edited answer: http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html